# Name of this PDE: $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, terminology

So I got an exercise to try some numerical methods on the following PDE:

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial x^3}$$

I tried to find some information about it, but I do not know how to call this equation and thus how to google it.

Anyone some ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: fix the math text